# Why np.clip(pd.Series(range(10)), 2,3) returns a Series?

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

`type(np.clip(pd.Series(range(10)), 2, 3))` is a `pd.Series`.

`type(np.clip(range(10), 2, 3))` is a `np.array`

Why `pd.Series` can keep its type after a `numpy` function applied to it?

Comment: because the underlying values in `pd.Series` is `np.array`?  `type(np.clip(pd.Series(range(10)).values, 2, 3))` gives `numpy.ndarray`

Comment: @JianxunLi I know I can use .value, but how does numpy know?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`pd.Series` have a clip method ([defined in pandas/core/generic.py](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/blob/master/pandas/core/generic.py#L3006)).

```
def clip(self, lower=None, upper=None, out=None, axis=None):
    ...
    result = self
    if lower is not None:
        result = result.clip_lower(lower, axis)
    if upper is not None:
        result = result.clip_upper(upper, axis)
    return result
```

`np.clip` ([defined in numpy/core/fromnumeric.py](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/numpy/core/fromnumeric.py#L1672)) defers to the first argument's `clip` method if it has one:

```
def clip(a, a_min, a_max, out=None):
    try:
        clip = a.clip
    except AttributeError:
        return _wrapit(a, 'clip', a_min, a_max, out)
    return clip(a_min, a_max, out)
```

The `Series.clip` method returns a `pd.Series`, so `np.clip` returns a `pd.Series`.
Of course, this also shows that you could use

```
pd.Series(range(10)).clip(2, 3)
```

instead of

```
np.clip(pd.Series(range(10)), 2, 3)
```

This is an example of "duck-typing" (*if it acts like a duck, quacks like a duck... it's a duck!*). We can get more mileage out of code if objects with the same interface (e.g. same method names) can be treated the same way.